# Problems connecting to Brownie/Rinkeby

Tags: python, powershell, environment-variables, solidity, brownie

I'm pretty new to this programming and maybe need more practice but I've been having problems trying to connect to the Rinkeby testnet and can't seem to see the problem (Windows 10, Powershell) not sure if it's the .env or how I set them up but I'll send the code or the respective files created with screenshots to see I someone could illuminate the problem. Copy pasted the code and some screenshots of the environment variables. Your help is very much appreciated. For some reason the export commands in the .env are seems as they are not executing(Third attachment).

Thank you

Error:

```
    Brownie v1.18.1 - Python development framework for Ethereum

BrownieSimpleStorageProject is the active project.

Running 'scripts\deploy.py::main'...
  File "C:\Users\jorge\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\brownie\_cli\run.py", line 51, in main
    return_value, frame = run(
  File "C:\Users\jorge\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\brownie\project\scripts.py", line 103, in run
    return_value = f_locals[method_name](*args, **kwargs)
  File ".\scripts\deploy.py", line 25, in main
    deploy_simple_storage()
  File ".\scripts\deploy.py", line 5, in deploy_simple_storage
    account = get_account()
  File ".\scripts\deploy.py", line 21, in get_account
    return accounts.add(config["wallets"]["from_key"])
KeyError: 'wallets'
```

deploy.py:

```
    from brownie import accounts, config, SimpleStorage, network


def deploy_simple_storage():
    account = get_account()
    simple_storage = SimpleStorage.deploy({"from": account})
    # Transaction
    # Call
    stored_value = simple_storage.retrieve()
    print(stored_value)
    transaction = simple_storage.store(15, {"from": account})
    transaction.wait(1)
    updated_value = simple_storage.retrieve()
    print(updated_value)


def get_account():
    if network.show_active() == "development":
        return accounts[0]
    else:
        return accounts.add(config["wallets"]["from_key"])


def main():
    deploy_simple_storage()
```

Here's the .env file:

```
export WEB3_INFURA_PROJECT_ID=xxx
export PRIVATE_KEY=xxxx
```

brownie-config.yaml file:

```
dotenv: .env
wallets:
    from_key: ${PRIVATE_KEY}
```

[Enviroment variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9oFVd.png)

[Environment variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjw0j.png)

[.env file export](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gX6h7.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`config` reads from brownie-config.yaml file which is in the root directory. make sure the location of the file is in root and its name is correct in the project.